# Morning : arrived / occurred / happened / came

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

Which is the **best** word to use from the ones given in title to use in the following sentence ?

> When the morning _____ , the murder was discovered.
>
> - arrived
> - occurred
> - happened
> - came

Please don't suggest any other word instead of those four given options as this was a MCQ pattern based question asked in my exam and I have to choose just from those four options.

Comment: "best" is subjective. "correct" is not. One person may prefer different word usage. Whoever created this question should reevaluate asking for objective answers to subjective questions.

Comment: The answer is *came!* Even I'm not sure why is that the answer! Hence, offering a bounty. It is indeed a thought-provoking question needs more attention!

Comment: @Flater I think a couple of the options sound better than others -- I don't see why the question shouldn't be asked.

Comment: Morning is something that occurs predictably every day.  It is associated with a time.  "Arrived" or "came" would both be commonly used.  You just wait for the time of morning to arrive and there it is. "Occurred" or "happened" are used with unpredictable things. They let you know the status of something that you couldn't know just by checking your watch or a calendar.  Between "arrived" and "came", there is no objective best answer.

Comment: @Ringo: As per the OP's explanation, this was an exam question. And such an exam question is inherently flawed as it relies on subjective preferences (e.g. some people might prefer "came" over "arrived"). It's impossible for us to know which word is the best word _according to the examinator_, unless only one word fits (which is not the case). "Best" does not mean the same thing as "most commonly used". One can argue that using fewer letters to convey the same message is better. And that doesn't even begin to scratch the topic of common usage varying per culture/region.

Answer (score 2):

***When the morning arrived*** is a very common phrase.

***When the morning occurred*** is very uncommon. I don't think I've ever heard this phrase before, and it sounds pretty awkward to me.

***When the morning happened*** is also uncommon, but is used in certain situations informally to mean that a big event or series of events occurred. For example, if you had a very busy morning filled with unusual events (say you got an unexpected promotion at work but then your car broke down in traffic), you could look back on your day and say, "Morning happened." In this case, you would leave out the article "the," so it doesn't seem like this option is the correct answer.

***When the morning came*** is also commonly used, but probably not as common as "arrived."

I would say "arrived" or "came" are both acceptable, but "arrived" is a little more common and is probably the answer they are looking for. But this is not a good question they ask, considering there are two viable options.

Comment: I as a non-native speaker would probably always choose **came**, and that's the correct answer. I would never use **occur** or **happened** with the word morning.

Comment: @SovereignSun Me too. But "arrived" is possible.

Comment: Note how your answer argues that "arrived" is the most correct, but the OP has confirmed in comments (below his own question) that the correct answer was "came". This is exactly why I argue that this question is flawed. "Best" is subjective. You clearly favor "arrived", but the examinator apparently favors "came". Neither of you is wrong, but your answers to the same question do conflict to a point where any given answer immediately implies that the other answers are the wrong answer to this question (a wrong answer = it's not the best choice, regardless of whether it's grammatically correct).

Comment: Yes, I agree -- I do point out that two answers are possible and that it's not a good question for the examinator to ask.

Comment: But I think also some learning took place -- including my own.

Comment: The conclusion is correct in that both *arrive* and *come* collocate with *morning*. However, after a cursory glance at the results from [BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/), [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and [GloWbE](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/), I've arrived at the conclusion that *come* is more frequently used with *morning* in all varieties of English; more precisely, by one order of magnitude. I therefore disagree, and I've voted this down.

Comment: @Flater Why stop with **_"examinator"_**? Consider instead a full _Bushification_ such as **_"examinifier"_** or **_"examinificator"_**.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: That's a mistranslation on my part, we use the word in my native language and it sounded correct to my ears (still does). However, [examinator is still defined in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/examinator), though it is labeled as chiefly Scottish.

Comment: @Flater I was just having a bit of fun with Bushification! Search for the word to learn more.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think "examinator" was a real word.

Answer (score 0):

- When the morning **came**, the murder was discovered.

As you are asking for the best word then choose **came** to be on the safe side.

**Came** here means happened, occured and arrived in the course of time. Took place and started to exist.

Comment: But then [winter can definitely arrive](https://www.amazon.com/Winter-Arrives-Secrets-Snow-1-ebook/dp/B00H2WE94C); in that way, even [night can occur!](http://www.education.vic.gov.au/school/teachers/teachingresources/discipline/science/continuum/Pages/daynight.aspx)

Comment: @MaulikV There is no way to award a bounty here based on the "best" choice between _came_ and _arrived_. In this context (and context here is critical, and cannot be considered in such methods as counting the number of collocations in a corpus), a native speaker is equally likely to use either one. What are you going to do, flip a coin?